# Get the dom element that represents the javascript tag where the code that is running is embebed

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
<script>
// I want to have the dom element of the script tag that is holding the code that goes here
</script>
```

If I do:

```
<script>
alert(this)
</script>
```

**this** is the window.

I want to access the script tag itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should find the `<script>` elements you have in your page.

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");

for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    var script = scripts[i];
    // Now you can do stuff with script
}
```

If you want the one the code is in I think you can do this:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var script = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
```

Just curious: what do you want to do with it once you've got it?

Comment: No, it's not a joke. The second part of the answer is not iterating over all the scripts. Do you want the CODE or the script DOM element?

Answer (score 0):

Found in another Stack (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6933817), maybe this answer solve your problem:

```
var target = document.documentElement; // start at the root element

while (target.childNodes.length && target.lastChild.nodeType == 1) { // find last HTMLElement child node
        target = target.lastChild;
}
// target is now the script element
alert(target.parentNode); // this is p
```