# Get DOM element where script tag is

Tags: javascript

I need to write a script that will use document.write to produce some output, but I need to know what element it is contained, example:

```
<p>
    paragraph 1
    <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</p>
```

I need to get a reference to the p tag...

thanks!

Comment: any document.write calls in test.js would produce their output at the exact location the script tag is. Unless you want to insert the text BEFORE the `paragraph 1` text...

Comment: I know, but I need to know the content of the p tag to write the output...

Comment: in jquery, something like `$("script[@src='test.js']").parent('p')` would do the trick.

Comment: @Marc: Lose the `@`.  `$("script[src='test.js']").parent('p')`

Comment: ah yeah. I'm in an xpath frame of mind today, I guess.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the time the script is run, the document is only partially loaded. So your script element would be the last node in the document:

```
var target = document.documentElement; // start at the root element
while (target.childNodes.length && target.lastChild.nodeType == 1) { // find last HTMLElement child node
    target = target.lastChild;
}
// target is now the script element
alert(target.parentNode); // this is p
```

Comment: This is not always true, however, e.g. inserting a new `<script>` element into an existing document.

Comment: @Phrogz though if you're inserting a new script tag you presumably have the ability to gather the information required before putting it in.

The other case it may not be true in is when writing additional tags with `document.write` before performing the check, so be sure to do the check within your script before you write anything out.

Answer (score 7):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/NqN3S/

```
<p>
    paragraph 1
    <script id="test" type="text/javascript">
        var scpt = document.getElementById( "test" );
        var p = scpt.parentNode;
        p.removeChild( scpt );
        alert( "old content: " + p.innerHTML );
        p.innerHTML = "some new content";
    </script>
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just put an id on the relevant p tag?

```
<p id="desiredTag">
    paragraph 1
    <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</p>
```

Then, you can do a `getElementById("desiredTag")` or `$("#desiredTag")`.

Comment: The content may be dynamic where you can't add the id/class to the parent, otherwise it would have been easiest fix.